# Extracting multiple date formats through regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract date from text in python. These are the possible texts and date patterns in it.

```
"Auction details: 14 December 2016, Pukekohe Park"
"Auction details: 17 Feb 2017, Gold Sacs Road"
"Auction details: Wednesday 27 Apr 1:00 p.m. (On site)(2016)"
"Auction details: Wednesday 27 Apr 1:00 p.m. (In Rooms - 923 Whangaa Rd, Man)(2016)"
"Auction details: Wed 27 Apr 2:00 p.m., 48 Viaduct Harbour Ave, Auckland, (2016)"
"Auction details: November 16 Wednesday 2:00pm at 48 Viaduct Harbour Ave, Auckland(2016)"
"Auction details: Thursday, 28th February '19"
"Auction details: Friday, 1st February '19"
```

This is what I have written so far,

```
mon = ' (?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?) '
day1 = r'\d{1,2}'
day_test = r'\d{1,2}(?:th)|\d{1,2}(?:st)' 
year1 = r'\d{4}'
year2 = r'\(\d{4}\)'
dummy = r'.*'
```

This captures cases 1,2.

```
match = re.search(day1 + mon + year1, "Auction details: 14 December 2016, Pukekohe Park")
print match.group()
```

This somewhat captures case 3,4,5. But it prints everything from the text, so in the below case, I want 25 Nov 2016, but the below regex pattern gives me 25 Nov 3:00 p.m. (On Site)(2016).

**So Question 1 : How to get only the date here?**

```
match = re.search(day1 + mon + dummy + year2, "Friday 25 Nov 3:00 p.m. (On Site)(2016)")
print match.group()
```

**Question 2 : Similarly, how do capture case 6,7 and 8 ?? What is the regex should be for that?**

If not, is there any other better way to capture date from these formats?

Comment: Yes. It always starts with auction details. But not sure how sorting helps here. It will be great if you can explain.

Comment: Try [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/wBHS0a/1)

Comment: Thanks. But it is not picking year in brackets. For cases 3,4,5,6.

Comment: I am happy to have multiple regex to handle this, it doesn't need to be one big regex. I can do if else loop to get it. As long as we cover all the scenarios.

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/wBHS0a/2) then?

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/4Oaf1Y/1, it will work if the last whole word consisting of 2 or 4 digits is the year.

Comment: Can you both add this as an answer.? I will try both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try

```
((?:(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\s+\d{1,2}(?:st|nd|rd|th)?|\d{1,2}(?:st|nd|rd|th)?\s+(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)))(?:.*(\b\d{2}(?:\d{2})?\b))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Oaf1Y/2).

Note I made all groups in the regex blocks non-capturing (`(Nov|Dec)` -> `(?:Nov|Dec)`), added `(?:st|nd|rd|th)?` optional group after day digit pattern, changed the year matching pattern to `\b\d{2}(?:\d{2})?\b` so that it only match 4- or  2-digit chunks as whole words, and created an alternation group to account for dates where day comes before month and vice versa.

The day and month are captured into Group 1 and the year is captured into Group 2, so the result is the concatenation of both.

**NOTE**: In case you need to match years in a safer way you may want to precise the year pattern. E.g., if you want to avoid matching the 4- or 2-digit whole words after `:`, add a negative lookbehind:

```
year1 = r'\b(?<!:)\d{2}(?:\d{2})?\b'
            ^^^^^^
```

Also, you may add word boundaries around the whole pattern to ensure a whole word match.

Here is the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9cko0A):

```
import re
mon = r'(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)'
day1 = r'\d{1,2}(?:st|nd|rd|th)?'
year1 = r'\b\d{2}(?:\d{2})?\b'
dummy = r'.*'

rx = r"((?:{smon}\s+{sday1}|{sday1}\s+{smon}))(?:{sdummy}({syear1}))?".format(smon=mon, sday1=day1, sdummy=dummy, syear1=year1)
# Or, try this if a partial number before a date is parsed as day:
# rx = r"\b((?:{smon}\s+{sday1}|{sday1}\s+{smon}))(?:{sdummy}({syear1}))?".format(smon=mon, sday1=day1, sdummy=dummy, syear1=year1)
strs = ["Auction details: 14 December 2016, Pukekohe Park","Auction details: 17 Feb 2017, Gold Sacs Road","Auction details: Wednesday 27 Apr 1:00 p.m. (On site)(2016)","Auction details: Wednesday 27 Apr 1:00 p.m. (In Rooms - 923 Whangaa Rd, Man)(2016)","Auction details: Wed 27 Apr 2:00 p.m., 48 Viaduct Harbour Ave, Auckland, (2016)","Auction details: November 16 Wednesday 2:00pm at 48 Viaduct Harbour Ave, Auckland(2016)","Auction details: Thursday, 28th February '19","Auction details: Friday, 1st February '19","Friday 25 Nov 3:00 p.m. (On Site)(2016)"]  
for s in strs:
    print(s)
    m = re.search(rx, s)
    if m:
        print("{} {}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2)))
    else:
        print("NO MATCH")
```

Output:

```
Auction details: 14 December 2016, Pukekohe Park
14 December 2016
Auction details: 17 Feb 2017, Gold Sacs Road
17 Feb 2017
Auction details: Wednesday 27 Apr 1:00 p.m. (On site)(2016)
27 Apr 2016
Auction details: Wednesday 27 Apr 1:00 p.m. (In Rooms - 923 Whangaa Rd, Man)(2016)
27 Apr 2016
Auction details: Wed 27 Apr 2:00 p.m., 48 Viaduct Harbour Ave, Auckland, (2016)
27 Apr 2016
Auction details: November 16 Wednesday 2:00pm at 48 Viaduct Harbour Ave, Auckland(2016)
November 16 2016
Auction details: Thursday, 28th February '19
28th February 19
Auction details: Friday, 1st February '19
1st February 19
Friday 25 Nov 3:00 p.m. (On Site)(2016)
25 Nov 2016
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)